# Nothing shown on screen when I try to run debug

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a splash screen but whenever I would run a "run without debugging" in vs code, nothing appears on screen but the default screen. I tried creating a navigator route, set the Home to different HomePage or SplashScreen but still there's no output in the screen. Is there a problem with my VSCode or my code is not enough? There's no indicator that there's an error in my code that's why I'm wondering why there's no output in the screen.

```
import 'dart:async';
import "package:flutter/material.dart"



void main() => runApp(MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
          home: LoginPage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
    }
    
    class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage()));
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                //logo here 
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/idkbank_logo.png',
                  height: 120,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
            title: Text("Welcome to IDKBank"),
          ),
          body: Container(child: Text("Home Page")),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: In your materialapp you are starting your app with LoginPage home parameter of MaterialApp, which I can't find its code in what you provided. So this might be either an error or you have it somewhere and it's blank.

Comment: If you want your app to render SplashScreen first you should provide it as a home screen, and implement a redirect logic from the Splash screen to home or login

Answer (score 1):

First, you're missing `;` in the end of second import.
Second , when you try to use context in `initState`, try to use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`
In you case, it should be

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage()));
      });
    });
  }
```

In `initState`, `build` funtion is not executed yet, the `context` is kind of empty. It the reason why you need [WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) here.